# How to calculate the number of possibilities?

Tags: probability

For example let's say we have a password combination of (a,b,c,d), if the password length was 1 then we'll have 4 possible passwords (a,b,c,d), now if the length was 2 then we'll have 20 possible passwords (a,b,...,dc,dd), I calculated this manually, I want the rule of calculating probability?

Comment: Uh, don't you mean 20, not 36?  If you can't calculate this, what makes you think the rule will be helpful?

Comment: And you said length 2, but (a,b,c,d) are length 1....you need to be clearer what it is you are looking for.  Do you want the probability of 1 or 2?

Comment: Sorry ! I new it was 20, but 36 was stuck in my head for some reason!

Comment: if the length was 2 that means (a,b,c,d,aa,ab,ac,ad,ba,..,da,db,dc,dd)

Comment: I think it's easier first to focus on the passwords that are _exactly_ $2$ symbols long. There are $16$ of those. Then for passwords with length _exactly_ $3$, there are $64$. The pattern so far is then $4,16,64$. Can you see how it continues? Then you can add them all together once you get to the longest length you want.

Comment: I will point out that you used the word **probability** multiple times, however your question has nothing to do with a probability, but rather **the number of possibilities**.  These are related concepts, but fundamentally different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every addition of a character multiplies the number of possibilities by $4$. For instance, if you have $N$ possibilities of passwords, and I now add another letter, then for any seuqence $[xyz...w]$ you can now generate four times:
$$[xyz...wa], [xyz...wb], [xyz...wc], [xyz...wd]$$.

So, for a password of length exactly $m$, we have $4^m$ possibilities.

According to your question I understand that you also consider all the shorter lengths as well, so the number of possibilities for password in length $m$ or less would be the sum of all possibilities, beginning from $n=1$, that is:

$$ A = 4 + 4^2 + ... + 4^m = \sum_{n=1}^m 4^n. $$

This is a geometric sum that has a closed form: $A = \frac{1-4^{m+1}}{1-4}-1$, where the deduction of $1$ is due to the fact that the formula applies when starting the summation from $n=0$ and not $n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want a password of length up to $n$.  Suppose also that you have $m$ possible digits to pick from...

The total possible 1-passwords would just be $m$ (m letters)

The total possible 2-passwords would just be $m^2$ (m letters times m letters)

...

The total possible n-passwords would just be $m^n$ (m letters times m letters times...times m letters) n times

So the total possible amount of passwords would be

$$m+m^2+m^3+...+m^n$$

This is basically the geometric series $-1$.  So

$$\sum_{k=1}^n{m^k}=\frac{m^{n+1}-1}{m-1}-1=\frac{m^{n+1}-m}{m-1}$$